# How to write a program that reads a message and counts the number of alph and digits then, replaces lower case by upper case characters?

Tags: c, string, loops, stdin

i want to use the same inputed message for the second part of the code but i can't. the first part is to count the number of alphabets and digits and the second part is to replace lower case by upper case characters. help me please!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MESSAGE 100
int main()
{
    char message[MESSAGE];
    int alphabet, digit, i;
    alphabet = digit = i = 0;
    printf("Please enter your message:\n");
    fgets(message, sizeof message, stdin);
    while (message[i] != '\0')
    {
        if ((message[i] >= 'a' && message[i] <= 'z')
                || (message[i] >= 'A' && message[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            alphabet++;
        }
        else if (message[i] >= '0' && message[i] <= '9')
        {
            digit++;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
        printf("Number of Alphabets in the string is : %d\n", alphabet);
        printf("Number of Digits in the string is : %d\n", digit);
        scanf("%i", message);
        int count, ch, i;
        for (i = 0; (message[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
        {
            ;
        }
        message[i] = '\0';
        count = i;
        printf("The given message is:%s\n", message);
        printf("Case changed message is:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            ch = islower(message[i]) ? toupper(message[i]) : tolower(message[i]);
            putchar(ch);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to count the alphanumeric characters first and then convert them into their opposite type (lower to upper and vice versa)?

Comment: Yes , i have most of the code but i just need something that makes the code use the same input without having to re enter it

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%i", message);
        int count, ch, i;
        for (i = 0; (message[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
        {
            ;
        }
        message[i] = '\0';`  What are you expecting this code snippet to perform?

Comment: regarding; `printf("Number of Alphabets in the string is : %d\n", alphabet);
        printf("Number of Digits in the string is : %d\n", digit);`  this is inside the `while()` loop, where the code is still calculating the counts.  Strongly suggest moving those two statements to after the `while()` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired operation(s)
3. produces the expected output
4. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
5. minimizes the scope of the variable `i`
6. since the numbers can never be less than 0, uses `size_t` rather than `int` in the variable definitions
7. properly checks for I/O errors and when an error occurs, passes the error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


#define MESSAGE 100


int main( void )
{
    char message[MESSAGE];
    size_t alphabet = 0;
    size_t digit = 0;
       
    printf("Please enter your message:\n");
    
    if( ! fgets(message, sizeof message, stdin) )
    {
        perror( "fgets failed:" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    printf( "The given message is:%s\n", message );
    
    for( size_t i = 0; message[i]; i++ )
    {
        if ( isalpha( message[i] ) )
        {
            alphabet++;
            message[i] = (islower(message[i]) ) ? (char)toupper(message[i]) : (char)tolower(message[i]);
        }
        
        else if ( isdigit( message[i] ))
        {
            digit++;
        }
    }
    
    printf("Number of Alphabets in the string is : %zu\n", alphabet);
    printf("Number of Digits in the string is : %zu\n", digit); 
    printf("Case changed message is: %s\n", message );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just coded again:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MESSAGE 100

int main(void) {
    char msg[MESSAGE];
    int alphabet = 0;
    int digit = 0;

    printf("Enter a message: ");
    fgets(msg, sizeof msg, stdin); // accepting the text

    for (int i = 0; msg[i]; i++) { // msg[i] says -> msg[i] != '\0'
        if (isalpha(msg[i])) alphabet++; // counting if alphabet occurs
        if (isdigit(msg[i])) digit++;    // counting if a digit occurs
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; msg[i]; i++)
        msg[i] = (isupper(msg[i])) ? tolower(msg[i]) : toupper(msg[i]);
        // converting from upper to lower and vice versa

    // printing the details of the given text        
    printf("There are %d letters and %d digits in the message.\n", alphabet, digit);

    // printing the converted text
    printf("The converted text is: %s\n", msg);

    return 0;
}
```

In the aforementioned code, the program will ask to get an input from the user and count both `alphabet` and `digit` wherever they're occurred and notice that here we've used `isdigit()` just to count if the letter given was a digit until the null-terminator occurs in the first For loop.

In the second loop, we've just converted each of the letter from upper to lower and vice versa and assigned them again into the same variable and printed them when the loop is exited successfully.

Also, notice that the punctuation marks ain't the member of either alphabet letters or digit, so they're not counted anywhere.

---

As a sample output:

```
Enter a message: Hello world, how are you 1234 doing? 
There are 24 letters and 4 digits in the message.
The converted text is: hELLO WORLD, HOW ARE YOU 1234 DOING?
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a clear question?

For the second part an easy trick is to look at an ASCII table and notice that 'A' is decimal 65 and 'a' is decimal 97. There is a difference of 32 between these so you can do a bitwise operation on all letters to convert to uppercase without converting the uppercase letters to lower.

This will mess up your numbers though, so you need to make sure you don't run this on those.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the same message then you don't need to input that again inside the while loop. Also, you have to increment 'i' for every case, if the current character is alphabet or digit, so don't put it in the else part.
Try the following implementation:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MESSAGE 100
int main()
{
    char message[MESSAGE];
    int alphabet, digit, i;
    alphabet = digit = i = 0;
    printf("Please enter your message:\n");
    fgets(message, sizeof message, stdin);
    while (message[i] != '\0')
    {
        if ((message[i] >= 'a' && message[i] <= 'z')
                || (message[i] >= 'A' && message[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            alphabet++;
        }
        else if (message[i] >= '0' && message[i] <= '9')
        {
            digit++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("Number of Alphabets in the string is : %d\n", alphabet);
    printf("Number of Digits in the string is : %d\n", digit);
    scanf("%s", message);
    int count, ch;
    message[i] = '\0';
    count = i;
    printf("The given message is:%s\n", message);
    printf("Case changed message is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ch = islower(message[i]) ? toupper(message[i]) : tolower(message[i]);
        putchar(ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked fine for me. It outputs the number of alphabet, digits and also converts the given string.

Answer (score 0):

"Don't tell me there's not one bit of difference between uppercase and lowercase letters, because that's exactly the difference."

In [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), you can toggle case by toggling the 6th least-significant bit.

```
'A' == 0x41  <->  0x61 == 'a'
'B' == 0x42  <->  0x62 == 'b'
'C' == 0x43  <->  0x63 == 'c'
             ...
'Z' == 0x5A  <->  0x7A == 'z'
```

That provides an easy of changing the case, and we can do it all in one pass.

```c
if (
      ( message[i] >= 'A' && message[i] <= 'Z' )
   || ( message[i] >= 'a' && message[i] <= 'z' )
) {
   ++letters;
   message[i] ^= 0x20;
}
else if ( message[i] >= '0' && message[i] <= '9' ) {
   ++digits;
}
```

This, like your original program, makes the following assumptions:

- The program will be compiled on an ASCII-based machine.
- The program will be compiled for an ASCII-based machine.
- You are only interested in the letters and digits in the ASCII character set.